# How can I get the first character after the selected text in InDesign?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I want to get the two characters surrounding my selected text in indesign.

I can get the character right before the selection with:

```
var myStory = app.selection[0].parentStory;
var myIndex = app.selection[0].index;

var myChar1 = myStory.characters[myIndex-1];
```

How can I get the first character right after the selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work with this:

```
var myStory = app.selection[0].parentStory;
var myIndex = app.selection[0].index;

var toplam = app.selection[0].characters.length;

var myChar1 = myStory.characters[myIndex-1];
var myChar2 = myStory.characters[myIndex+toplam];
```